# convert XML to DataFrame using python script

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe, lxml

I'm trying to convert the below xml data to a dataframe.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TEST>
    <Node1L1>1</Node1L1>
    <Node2L1>FP</Node2L1>
    <SUBL1>
        <M>
            <PAR>
                <NAME>A</NAME>
                <TYPE>f</TYPE>
                <DESC />
                <VAL>1,2,3,4,5,6</VAL>
            </PAR>
            <PAR>
                <NAME>B</NAME>
                <TYPE>f</TYPE>
                <DESC />
                <VAL>10,20,30,40,50,60</VAL>
            </PAR>
            <PAR>
                <NAME>C</NAME>
                <TYPE>f</TYPE>
                <DESC />
                <VAL>11,22,33,44,55,66</VAL>
            </PAR>
            <PAR>
                <NAME>D</NAME>
                <TYPE>f</TYPE>
                <DESC />
                <VAL>a,b,c,d,e,f</VAL>
            </PAR>
            <PAR>
                <NAME>E</NAME>
                <TYPE>f</TYPE>
                <DESC />
                <VAL>aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff</VAL>
            </PAR>
        </M>
        <M>
            <PAR>
                <NAME>A_test</NAME>
                <VAL>0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5</VAL>
            </PAR>
        </M>            
    </SUBL1>
</TEST>
```

I need to extract only the first **M** tag **PAR** child nodes for the names **A,C,E**

This is just a sample file but the file I have is a large one with lots of **PAR** tags in 2 **M** tags. I was able to do the XML conversion using the below code but it also takes the second **M** tag **PAR** tags as well.

```
df = pd.read_xml(path2file, xpath="//*[local-name()='PAR']")
```

I'm trying to find a way to improve the `xpath=` string so it will extract only the first **M** tag data into a dataframe.
Also if there is any alternate method, please let me know. I would also like to avoid the empty **DESC** column in the nodes as well.

Comment: Are you looking for this: [`.//M/PAR[NAME=("A", "C", "E")]`](http://xpather.com/34MaJGEP)? If you need to take only first element, just add index -> [`.//M[1]/PAR[NAME=("A","C","E")]`](http://xpather.com/92q4MItu)?

Answer (score 1):

See below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd


xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TEST>
    <Node1L1>1</Node1L1>
    <Node2L1>FP</Node2L1>
    <SUBL1>
        <M>
            <PAR>
                <NAME>A</NAME>
                <TYPE>f</TYPE>
                <DESC />
                <VAL>1,2,3,4,5,6</VAL>
            </PAR>
            <PAR>
                <NAME>B</NAME>
                <TYPE>f</TYPE>
                <DESC />
                <VAL>10,20,30,40,50,60</VAL>
            </PAR>
            <PAR>
                <NAME>C</NAME>
                <TYPE>f</TYPE>
                <DESC />
                <VAL>11,22,33,44,55,66</VAL>
            </PAR>
            <PAR>
                <NAME>D</NAME>
                <TYPE>f</TYPE>
                <DESC />
                <VAL>a,b,c,d,e,f</VAL>
            </PAR>
            <PAR>
                <NAME>E</NAME>
                <TYPE>f</TYPE>
                <DESC />
                <VAL>aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff</VAL>
            </PAR>
        </M>
        <M>
            <PAR>
                <NAME>A_test</NAME>
                <VAL>0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5</VAL>
            </PAR>
        </M>            
    </SUBL1>
</TEST>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
pars = list(root.find('.//M'))
data = [[p.text for p in  list(par) if p.text] for par in pars if par.find('NAME').text in ['A','C','E']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ['NAME','TYPE','VAL'])
print(df)
```

output

```
  NAME TYPE                VAL
0    A    f        1,2,3,4,5,6
1    C    f  11,22,33,44,55,66
2    E    f  aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff
```

Answer (score 1):

From docs of [`pandas.read_xml()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html#pandas.read_xml) you see that `lxml` is used as a default parser.

Unfortunately, [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/) *(as well as built-in [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree))* doesn't support [XPath 2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/), so generic solution [`.//M[1]/PAR[NAME=('A','C','E')]`](http://xpather.com/SDA2EbNE) won't suite. But we can use an [XPath 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/) alternative — [`.//M[1]/PAR[NAME='A' or NAME='C' or NAME='E']`](http://xpather.com/vJUK6KjL).

Final code will be next:

```py
df = pd.read_xml(
    path2file,
    xpath=".//M[1]/PAR[NAME='A' or NAME='C' or NAME='E']"
)
```

P.S. Haven't tested it, so pin me if it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Thanks Olvin. This works. I was trying to pass the filter list as itself so unable to get any results. Thanks.

Comment: @ArunakiriVenkatachalam, you can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer if it helped you.